# How does Terrain following work on height map?

Tags: algorithm, xna-4.0, terrain, heightmap

I'm writing a 3D world game which consists of a terrain map (generated by brownian motion algorithm) and a simple avatar. My goal is to make the avatar move smoothly between points of different height. Originally, I simply translate from start location to stop location, then set the height of this point based on the height value of a pair (x, z). Unfortunately the movement is completely off. I searched online I found several algorithms to create a smooth movement but I was not able to put them together. I just started to lean graphics for a month, so sorry for my dull knowledge.

My height map size is 512 * 512, and the spacing between each vertex is 150. Base on these values, I create a square around my destination as follows:

```
/*
                        * A            B
                        * --------------
                        * |            |
                        * |    x       |
                        * |            |
                        * |            |
                        * --------------
                        * C            D
                        */

                // build square ABCD around stopLocation
                int x = (int)stopLocation.X / 150;
                int z = (int)stopLocation.Z / 150;

                Vector3 A = new Vector3(x * 150, stage.surfaceHeight(x * 150, z * 150), z * 150);
                Vector3 B = new Vector3((x + 1) * 150, stage.surfaceHeight((x + 1) * 150, z * 150), z * 150);
                Vector3 C = new Vector3(x * 150, stage.surfaceHeight(x * 150, (z + 1) * 150), (z + 1) * 150);
                Vector3 D = new Vector3((x + 1) * 150, stage.surfaceHeight((x + 1) * 150, (z + 1) * 150), (z + 1) * 150);
```

I use a simple algorithm to determine my destination plane:

```
public bool isInUpperPlane(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, Vector3 C, Vector3 D, Vector3 point) {

            /*
                   ^ y
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |  A       B
                   ----------------------------> x
                  /          /
                 /      x   /
              C /_________ / D
               /
              /
             /
            v z
            */

            // consider A as the origin
            if (Math.Abs(point.X - A.X) + Math.Abs(point.Z - A.Z) >= 150)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Next I construct a plane the 3 vertices (either ABC or BCD):

```
     Plane destPlane;
     if (isInUpperPlane(A, B, C, D, stopLocation)) {
         destPlane = new Plane(A, B, C);
     }
     else {
         destPlane = new Plane(B, C, D);
     }
```

Then I project this my start location to this plane normal, and translate my avatar to this location:

```
Vector3 normal = destPlane.Normal;
Vector3 r = projectVectorToPlane(startLocation, normal);
Orientation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(startLocation);
```

But doing this make my avatar stays still. It's very very wrong, but I really don't know how it actually works. The 3D world is just too confusing at this moment. Could anyone help me explain what's go wrong? An minimal working example would be greatly appreciated.

This is my original implementation, (not smooth following)

```
public void updateMovableObject() {
            Vector3 startLocation = Translation;
            Vector3 stopLocation = Translation;

            Orientation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(-1 * Translation);        // move to origin
            Orientation *= Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw);                       // rotate
            Orientation *= Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch);
            Orientation *= Matrix.CreateRotationZ(roll);

            stopLocation += ((step * stepSize) * Forward);                    // move forward    

            // if collision, reset location and return
            if (model.IsCollidable && collision(stopLocation)) {
                Orientation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(startLocation);        // don't move
                return;
            }

            // no collision test if move on terrain
            if (stage.withinRange(this.Name, stopLocation)) {
                Orientation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(stopLocation);         // move forward
            }
            else { // off terrain, reset location
                Orientation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(startLocation);        // don't move
            }
        }
        stage.setSurfaceHeight(this);


 public void setSurfaceHeight(Object3D anObject3D) {
            float terrainHeight = terrain.surfaceHeight((int)(anObject3D.Translation.X / spacing), (int)(anObject3D.Translation.Z / spacing));
            anObject3D.Translation = new Vector3(anObject3D.Translation.X, terrainHeight, anObject3D.Translation.Z);
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
 public float surfaceHeight(int x, int z) {
            if (x < 0 || x > 511 || z < 0 || z > 511) 
                return 0.0f;  // index valid ?
            return (float)terrainHeight[x, z];
        }
```

Comment: What does your surfaceHeight method look like?

Comment: I was a little confused on what you are trying to achieve above, but are you just looking for a way to find the height of an object if the object is in the middle of 4 vertices?

Comment: @LuisEstrada: I searched online, and found that most people suggest doing is to find the normal of the plane where destination lands. Then adjust the normal vector of the avatar to match that plane normal. That's what I understood. In my above code, first I tried to find a triangular plane of my destination, then calculate that plane normal. Next I project my avatar normal to the plane normal. Still, I'm not sure if this is a right approach. I wish I could describe the problem better! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have seems like a lot of work to put your avatar on the terrain at a given point. Here's the method I use to calculate terrain height. Simply pass in your X and Z coordinates and it will return the terrain height. In this case, the `scaleFactor` you pass in should be 150. Given something like this you just pick two pairs of X,Z coordinates, get the terrain height at each, and set these points as your start and end points, and then call this method each frame to make sure the avatar stays on (or at least above) the terrain.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the height of the terrain at given horizontal coordinates.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xPos">X coordinate</param>
/// <param name="zPos">Z coordinate</param>
/// <returns>Height at given coordinates</returns>
public float GetTerrainHeight(float xPos, float zPos, float scaleFactor)
{
    // we first get the height of four points of the quad underneath the point
    // Check to make sure this point is not off the map at all
    int x = (int)(xPos / scaleFactor);      
    int z = (int)(zPos / scaleFactor);      

    int xPlusOne = x + 1;
    int zPlusOne = z + 1;

    float triZ0 = (this.heightData[x, z]);
    float triZ1 = (this.heightData[xPlusOne, z]);
    float triZ2 = (this.heightData[x, zPlusOne]);
    float triZ3 = (this.heightData[xPlusOne, zPlusOne]);

    float height = 0.0f;
    float sqX = (xPos / scaleFactor) - x;
    float sqZ = (zPos / scaleFactor) - z;
    if ((sqX + sqZ) < 1)
    {
        height = triZ0;
        height += (triZ1 - triZ0) * sqX;
        height += (triZ2 - triZ0) * sqZ;
    }
    else
    {
        height = triZ3;
        height += (triZ1 - triZ3) * (1.0f - sqZ);
        height += (triZ2 - triZ3) * (1.0f - sqX);
    }
    return height;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the code to calculate the surface normal at any point on the terrain.

```
/// <summary>
/// Setup <see cref="Terrain"/> normals. Normals are used for lighting, normal mapping, and physics with terrain.
/// </summary>
private void SetupTerrainNormals(float scaleFactor)
{
    VertexTerrain[] terrainVertices = new VertexTerrain[this.size * this.size];
    this.normals = new Vector3[this.size, this.size];

    // Determine vertex positions so we can figure out normals in section below.
    for(int x = 0; x < this.size; ++x)
        for(int z = 0; z < this.size; ++z)
        {
            terrainVertices[x + z * this.size].Position = new Vector3(x * scaleFactor, this.heightData[x, z], z * scaleFactor);
        }

    // Setup normals for lighting and physics (Credit: Riemer's method)
    int sizeMinusOne = this.size - 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < sizeMinusOne; ++x)
        for (int z = 1; z < sizeMinusOne; ++z)
        {
            int ZTimesSize = (z * this.size);
            Vector3 normX = new Vector3((terrainVertices[x - 1 + ZTimesSize].Position.Y - terrainVertices[x + 1 + ZTimesSize].Position.Y) / 2, 1, 0);
            Vector3 normZ = new Vector3(0, 1, (terrainVertices[x + (z - 1) * this.size].Position.Y - terrainVertices[x + (z + 1) * this.size].Position.Y) / 2);

            // We inline the normalize method here since it is used alot, this is faster than calling Vector3.Normalize()
            Vector3 normal = normX + normZ;
            float length = (float)Math.Sqrt( (float)((normal.X * normal.X) + (normal.Y * normal.Y) + (normal.Z * normal.Z)) );
            float num = 1f / length;
            normal.X *= num;
            normal.Y *= num;
            normal.Z *= num;

            this.normals[x, z] = terrainVertices[x + ZTimesSize].Normal = normal;    // Stored for use in physics and for the
                                                                                     // quad-tree component to reference.
        }
}
```

And here's the code to retrieve the normal at any point.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the normal of a position on the heightmap.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xPos">X position on the map</param>
/// <param name="zPos">Z position on the map</param>
/// <returns>Normal vector of this spot on the terrain</returns>
public Vector3 GetNormal(float xPos, float zPos, float scaleFactor)
{
    int x = (int)(xPos / scaleFactor);
    int z = (int)(zPos / scaleFactor);

    int xPlusOne = x + 1;
    int zPlusOne = z + 1;

    Vector3 triZ0 = (this.normals[x, z]);
    Vector3 triZ1 = (this.normals[xPlusOne, z]);
    Vector3 triZ2 = (this.normals[x, zPlusOne]);
    Vector3 triZ3 = (this.normals[xPlusOne, zPlusOne]);

    Vector3 avgNormal;
    float sqX = (xPos / scaleFactor) - x;
    float sqZ = (zPos / scaleFactor) - z;
    if ((sqX + sqZ) < 1)
    {
        avgNormal = triZ0;
        avgNormal += (triZ1 - triZ0) * sqX;
        avgNormal += (triZ2 - triZ0) * sqZ;
    }
    else
    {
        avgNormal = triZ3;
        avgNormal += (triZ1 - triZ3) * (1.0f - sqZ);
        avgNormal += (triZ2 - triZ3) * (1.0f - sqX);
    }
    return avgNormal;
}
```

Comment: I wonder does your method produce smooth following? I actually have my avatar correctly on the terrain, it just doesn't follows the curve smoothly though. Anyway, I will experiment with it a bit. Thank you.

Comment: If it follows your terrain smoothly then all you should need is to create some wandering/pathing using X,Z coords. For more realistic pathing you'll probably want to account for terrain slope so as not to move over very steep terrain. My method with produce results that are exact to the terrain, so as long as your terrain is smooth you should be ok, however with 150 units between verts on an axis it will be hard to have anything smooth I would imagine.

Comment: I tried out your example and it worked great. Now my avatar *always* stands above the terrain ;). However, it still didn't produce smoothing following.   To implement "smooth" terrain following, what should I do next? And I still want to understand why project the normal of my current position to the plane normal did not work? Could you help me on this as well?

Comment: I see, when changing normals you want a smooth transition. I would check a few positions in front on the avatar to check for normal changes in front of it, and if found I would begin linearly interpolating the avatars normal a but each frame until it lines up with the point it is heade towards. Calculating the normals at each point requires using the vertices around it, I'm no longer at a computer so I can't easily find this for you, but you'll want to google for "Calculating surface normal binormal tangent" to get some info on it.

Comment: I got back to my computer and added to my post the method I use for calculating and storing the normals in my terrain, and the method I use for retrieving those normals. If it helps this is all part of an engine I've written, which is open source, so you can see it working and reference that if you would like, it's located here: http://quickstartengine.codeplex.com/